# How to prevent Django form from saving if no change was made?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How can I prevent a Django ModelForm from saving, for example, the qty column, if a user doesn't change that specific column?

My example:

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

forms.py:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    rows_per_page = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=1)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['sku', 'qty', 'sell_price']

ProductFormSet = forms.modelformset_factory(Product, form=ProductForm, extra=0)
```

views.py:

```
class Inventory(FormView):
    form_class = ProductFormSet

    def get(self, req):
        query = Product.objects.filter('condition')
        form = ProductFormSet(queryset=query)
        return render(req, 'base.html', {'form':form})

    def post(self, req):
        query = Product.objects.filter('condition')
        form = ProductFormSet(queryset=query)
        if product_form.is_valid():
            product_form.save()
        return render(req, 'base.html', {'form':form})
```

data:

```
Product.objects.create(
    name = 'test product',
    sku = 1,
    qty = 0,
    price = 50,
)
```

The problem comes when 2 users are looking at the same queryset at the same time.  If user1 decides to modify the qty of *test product*, then saves the page while user2 is still on that page, if user2 makes any changes to any of the columns (other than qty), the qty change that user1 made will be overwritten back to the original value.

My solution before Django was to pass an object of price, qty, and sku to the window, then use jQuery to remove unchanged inputs before submit:

```
$('#product_form').submit(function() {
  const items = window.items;
  $(this).find('input').each(function() {
    //check if input value has changed, if not, remove it from the form
  })
});
```

Is there a better approach to this problem that I'm not thinking about?

Any advice / links to related topics is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you do it in the view? Whenever a user submits the `product_form`, check if all the fields' values in the submitted `Product` object is the same with the one saved in the database.

Answer (score 1):

This will always need to be handled by the frontend. When you submit the POST request the queryset is re-evaluated before saving the form/formset meaning the changes from your second user will have been committed to the database.

Matching the data from your POST to the price of the matching instance in the queryset will show that your price is different and *update* the instance (aka reverting back to the original price).

Consider the following scenario:

1. User 1 GET InventoryView `product_1.price = 5`
2. User 2 GET InventoryView then POST `product_1.price = 10`
3. User 1 POST InventoryView `data = [{'id': 1, 'price': 5}, {'id': 2, 'price': 100}]`

   - queryset is re-evaluated so `product_1.price = 10` even though you haven't changed an data
   - matching the price against the instance the logic on the backend would say that you *changed* the price to 5 even though the data wasn't modified from the original GET request